В java swing отображаются не корректно некоторые относительно редкие языки
Пишу многоязыковое приложение. Создал демо:
public class SwingLang {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,3000);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        String[] x = new String[11];
        //по русски текст "Проверка коонфигурации и аккаунта"
        x[0] = "तैयारी और खाता जांच";   //телугу
        x[1] = "తయారీ మరియు ఖాతా తనిఖీ"; //тамильский
        x[2] = "தயாரிப்பு மற்றும் கணக்கு சரிபார்ப்பு";  //тайский
        x[3] = "การเตรียมและตรวจสอบบัญชี";  //сингальский
        x[4] = "සූදානම් වීම සහ ගිණුම පරීක්‍ෂාව";    //лаосский
        x[5] = "तयारी र खाता जाँच"; //непальский
        x[6] = "തയ്യാറാക്കലും അക്കൗണ്ട് പരിശോധനയും";//малаялам
        x[7] = "ກຳລັງກະກຽມ ແລະ ກວດສອບບັນຊີ";    //
        x[8] = "កំពុងត្រួតពិនិត្យ";         //кхмерский
        x[9] = "તૈયારી અને એકાઉન્ટ તપાસ";   //гуджарати
        x[10] = "ব্যবস্থা এবং একাউন্ট দেখা";    //бенгальский

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(x[i]);
            System.out.println(x[i]);
            panel.add(label);
        }

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

Эти языки в swing приложении отображаются квадратиками. Цель: сделать хотя бы больше половины отображаемыми корректно.
Эти все языки отображаются корректно на Linux Ubuntu.
На Windows вывод в консоль так же корректный.
Пробовал подставлять шрифты через класс Font, но и это не помогло. Хотя сама идея со шрифтами не очень нравится, учитывая, что Linux читает и без них.
Больше всего интересует, что можно сделать мне, как разработчику, с кодом или параметрами его запуска, что бы не писать инструкцию что делать пользователю с его ОС

а какое у вас JDK - от оракла или другое?

Oracle Open JDK 17 и 21 пробовал. Дальше по версиям не шел т.к. проблемы с Lombok начинаются

Как пробовали шрифты подставлять и что не получилось/не понравилось? Надо выбирать из них те, которые поддерживают Unicode и данный набор символов, загружаемый дефолтный скорее всего их не поддерживает. Шрифт можно положить к исходникам и подтягивать динамически через Font.createFont. Добавление такого кода перед циклом делает на Windows читаемым 8 языков из 10: Font font = new Font("Arial Unicode MS", Font.PLAIN, 14); и UIManager.put("Label.font", font);. Подобрав шрифт или меняя их в зависимости от языка можно добиться желаемого.

Шрифты добавлял label.setFont(font);. Попробовал и указанный Вами шрифт через setFont и через UIManager - ничего не поменялось

Оказалось, что я попробовал мало шрифтов. Спасибо!

Шрифт еще может быть не установлен в системе, поэтому такой код он тоже проглотит, но подставит все равно дефолтный: new Font("SKDFJLSDKJFL", Font.PLAIN, 14);. Либо ваш вариант, либо еще вариант таскать с собой те, которые поддерживают нужное и работают. Читать их в поток и подгружать через Font.createFont.

//берем все доступные шрифты
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(x[i]);
    for (Font font : ge.getAllFonts()) {
        //если шрифт спосоен отобразить данный текст
        if (font.canDisplayUpTo(x[i]) == -1) {
            //установить шрифт для label
            label.setFont(font.deriveFont(15f));
            break;
        }
    }
    panel.add(label);
}

